# angularJs stateprovider sub state doesn't load controller and template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I created this small app where I have following states:

restricted.route.js

```
$stateProvider.state('restricted', {
  url: '/restricted',
  templateUrl: 'app/restricted/restricted.html',
  abstract: true
});
```

pages.route.js

```
$stateProvider.state('restricted.pages', {
  url: '/pages',
  templateUrl: 'app/restricted/pages/pages.html',
  controller: 'pagesController',
  controllerAs: 'vmPages'
});
```

detail.route.js

```
$stateProvider.state('restricted.pages.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    controller: 'pageDetailController',
    controllerAs: 'vmDetail',
    templateUrl: 'app/restricted/pages/detail/detail.html'
});
```

app.run.js

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/restricted/dashboard');
```

When I load the URL #/restricted/pages everything works fine. Controller is loaded and view is shown.
When I load the URL #/restricted/pages/1 the controller and view from the state 'restricted.pages' is loaded and executed.
The state is clearly recognized, because the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise is not executed.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it intentional to have the details as a substate of the pages (list?) state? If so, you need to place an `<div ui-view></div>` into the template named `app/restricted/pages/pages.html`.

If that was not your intention, I recommend to rename the detail state to something like `restricted.pages_detail` as every dot introduces a nested level in the state definitions.

Comment: So stupid! It was not my intention. Changing the state to restricted.pages_detail solved it all... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies in the HTML, the nested state should be loaded in a ui-view tag on the parent element.